# Scrape all API endpoints

Tags: node.js, api, web-scraping, endpoint

Is there any way to scrape or get all endpoints of public API without any docs etc.? I have only the URL for main endpoint that returns "Backend works".

Comment: If the API does not have a built-in discovery mechanism (a-la graphiql), then your only option is to brute-force it. And even then, it's not even remotely a guarantee to find all the endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

No. There's no generic way of detecting all possible public API endpoints.